# Removed css class have still effects

Tags: asp.net, css

```
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have added only one(above) stylesheet in my page. I have buttons as menu and there `CssClaas` is set to `mbt`. If I remove `CssClass="mbt"` from a button tag, I will see that button totally with no style.

```
<asp:Button ID="mHome1" runat="server" Text="Home" CssClass="mbt"
PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
```

But I have already removed `mbt` from `Styles/Site.css`. I have no `mbt` class in my whole project now, but still its effect is there. I have tried to rebuild project and restart visual-studio, but its effect is not going any way. How? Why?

Comment: what are you viewing it in? Not something silly like a cached file, right?

Comment: Might be. I am trying to clear cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to clear your browser's cache? Maybe the stylesheet file is cached.

With most browsers, you can force a reload of all files by clicking Shift-F5 or Ctrl-F5.

In my experience, I had the most cache-related problems when using Google Chrome.

In Internet Explorer, there is a useful option (in Internet Options -> General tab -> Browsing History -> Settings) where you can tell the browser to check for newer versions of files every time a page is loaded. This setting can be especially useful while developping a web application.

In firefox, you can find the settings in the Options dialog, under Advanced -> Network.

Comment: Sorry how to do that? Clear recent history?

Comment: Yes, I think this is most likely the issue. Especially if your are testing in IE.

Comment: You can either clear the history and quit the browser. Or try testing the page out in a second browser if you would just like to check it real fast.

Comment: Yes I was viewing cached version? But it has not been happening in past? How to avoid it in future? I should not have to do this manually

Comment: You can't really help it. Browser have the caching features built in. You'll get the hang of resetting the browser ever once and a while by habit when working with CSS. I usually just pop over to another browser when I see a change that should be taking place but isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting, then re-uploading the css.

Answer (score 1):

clear the browser cache. `Ctrl + Shift + Del`